# Working out the Busiest Day using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, unix-timestamp

I have a table with a timestamp in unixtimestamp for everytime someone logs into the system. I would like to work out the busiest day.

Im a little lost as to where to start, i believe its that you need to work out a count for each day stored into the database (or some kind of string between start and end of the logs?)

Database Structure for `logs`

Example :

```
user  | action         | timestamp
admin | User Logged In | 1395257767
```

User being "Username"

Action being "User Logged In"

Timestamp being Unixtimestamp given at the time they login to the system.

Any help would be a great start

SQLFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66d4293

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like thi.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) c, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME( timestamp) ) day FROM log 
GROUP BY  day ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT 1;
```

`DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME( timestamp ))` converts to a datetime and then a date.

By the way, you might consider storing your dates as `datetime` or `timestamp` structures.  Storing as unix timestamps and then having to convert to useable dates is less than ideal.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a53d1/2

Comment: Would this command and using the FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) allow me to also do a Busiest Month? or is there a different command for doing Months as compaired to Days ?

Comment: @CliffordYetiMapp [The MySQL documentation is pretty good, use it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract)

Comment: Yeah, you can basically do busiest anything.  Try `YEAR()`, `MONTH()`, things from above doc link. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a53d1/5

Answer (score 2):

just a quick guess of what you are asking for:

```
 select date(timestamp),count(*) from logs group by date(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))
```

example output from a database I tested the query on:

```
+---------------+----------+
| date(timestamp) | count(*) |
+---------------+----------+
| 2013-12-13    |     4978 |
| 2013-12-14    |     5016 |
| 2013-12-15    |     4999 |
| 2013-12-16    |     5002 |
| 2013-12-17    |     4995 |
| 2013-12-18    |     5000 |
| 2013-12-19    |     5001 |
| 2013-12-20    |     5001 |
| 2013-12-21    |     5001 |
| 2013-12-22    |     4713 |
| 2013-12-30    |     4892 |
| 2013-12-31    |     5064 |
| 2014-01-01    |     5024 |
| 2014-01-02    |     5001 |
| 2014-01-03    |     5002 |
| 2014-01-04    |     5001 |
| 2014-01-05    |     4970 |
| 2014-01-06    |     4989 |
| 2014-01-07    |     4995 |
| 2014-01-08    |     5004 |
| 2014-01-09    |     2531 |
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the busiest day use [DAYOFWEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek)

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(timestamp),COUNT(*) FROM logs GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK(timestamp)
```